# Core Data, Dynamic Properties or CASE Sort?

Tags: sql, objective-c, core-data

I'd like to implement a dynamic property on a Core Data model but am unclear as to whether this is supported, and if so... how?

The idea is to have a model with a set number of non-dynamic fields, such as created_at, updated_at, start_at, end_at, etc.  These would be dates.  I'd then like to include a dynamic property called "is_archive" which would perform a basic check against the "end_at" property and return True or False.

I know that I can update the Model to add a custom property, but am unclear as to how I could implement this so that I can include "is_archive" in an NSSortDescriptor.

Right now, I have:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest init] alloc];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"start_at" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort1,nil]];
```

What I'd like to do is add:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"is_archive" ascending:NO];
```

In SQL, I would normally do this with a CASE statement, such as:

```
select *
from event e
order by case when e.end_at > curdate() then 1 else 0 end desc, e.end_at asc;
```

So I suppose the question is:

How can I do a "CASE WHEN x > y THEN true ELSE false END" with a Core Data NSSortDescriptor, or the equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David,

It is difficult, if not impossible, to make a fetch request using dynamic properties. In Core Data, one typically over fetches an entity and then refines the resultant array using predicates, such as with -filteredArrayUsingPredicate:. While at first glance this appears to be wasteful, it is relatively memory efficient and fast.

Andrew

Comment: Adonoho, how would I filter the list using a Predicate? Is it not possible to utilize SQLite's built-in functionality for the "CASE" statement? I just want to have my data sorted so that "archived" (if end_at > now) is at the bottom, but otherwise ... the rest of the sorting is performed on the 'start_at'

Comment: David, You are still thinking of Core Data app as if it were a SQL app. It isn't. Most features of SQL are NOT reflected out into Core Data. They want you to think in terms of set operations on your data model. This also means you structure your model differently. This takes some time to internalize. To your question, I think I showed you the exact call to filter your array. If your problem is that the predicate language is not as capable as SQL, then I can't help you. In Core Data, you repeatedly filter until you get the set you want. Andrew

Comment: Adonoho, what if your using an NSFetchedResultsController? I'm not aware of any way to add additional filters after the NSFetchRequest is executed.

Comment: David, The NSFetchedResultsController has some limitations. In complex cases, I do not use the NSFetchedResultsController but manage the table view directly. In those cases, I listen for the didSave notifications and filter those items into the table view directly. I can then have both the same complex predicate and sorting behavior as needed. Such is the cost of complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

use NSPredicate

check out this link http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/core-data-one-line-fetch.html

---edit

I can't tell you how to do this in clear and good code. But you can create two arrays using predicate - one with array of is_archived set to YES and the other set to NO, apply sort descriptors to both and concatenate them. I know that's pretty dirty...

Comment: I don't follow.  How does an NSPredicate affect the sort order of the results? I want the returned records in the NSFetchRequest to be sorted based on the 'is_archive' and 'start_at'.  Archived should appear below active items, and both items should be sorted based on the 'start_at'.